# Can QAbstractItemModel.beginInsertRows() be given an overestimate of the number of rows to be inserted?

Tags: pyside, qtsql

I am using a custom QSqlTableModel class to edit an SQL table, which has certain constraints (e.g. a UNIQUE constraint). Because of these SQL constraints, at the time .insertRows() is called on a new batch of rows, it is not known which (or how many) of those rows will be successfully inserted. Therefore, when reimplementing the .insertRows() function, is it kosher to give .beginInsertRows() the upper limit of the number of rows which will be inserted, or will this cause problems down the line?

See https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.beginInsertRows

Comment: Row insertion is not necessarily related to record insertion. You could always add a row, then ensure that the new record is unique, and if it's not, you remove the row. Unfortunately, though, your description if too vague, and we can hardly tell you more unless you clarify why and what you're "customizing" on your model.

Comment: @musicamante Excellent point. In trying to call .insertRows() to add blank rows before attempting to add the data, however, I ran into another problem (which I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75086614/qsqltablemodel-insertrow-only-works-once). Basically, I can only insert a single row at a time, then the function stops working.